# Is there a way to list all sub-arrays of given sum in a time-efficient manner?

Tags: java, arraylist, time, time-complexity, game-development

I am implementing a card game in Java. I have a set of cards, each one has a value, given the fact that:

I choose a card X (let's suppose its value is 8)

```
X:8
```

I have an ArrayList of cards with their values

```
[A:5,B:2,C:2,D:1,E:1]
```

I want to list all the possible **sum combination** of cards that match card X's value, that is

```
[A,B,D],[A,B,E],[A,C,D],[A,D,E]
```

Explanation: [A, B, D] => A + B + D = 5 + 2 + 1 = 8

CODE:

```
if (card.GetValue() < valore) {
    int i = Tavolo.indexOf(card);
    int j = i + 1;
    int currentsum = card.GetValue();

    if (i < Tavolo.size() - 2) {
        while (j <= (Tavolo.size() - 1)) {
            Carta d = Tavolo.get(j);
            currentsum += d.GetValue();
            AggiungiPotenziale(index, d);

            if (currentsum == valore) {
                AggiungiPotenziale(index, card);
                index++;
                currentsum = card.GetValue();
            }

            if (currentsum > valore) {
                RimuoviPotenziale(index);
            }

            j++;
        }

        if (currentsum < valore) {
            RimuoviPotenziale(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The last solution must be `[A,C,E]`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist how could i implement a time-efficient algorithm that lists all possibile sum combinations